# SQL pull containing IN and NOT IN

Tags: sql, ms-access

```
SELECT OrderHeader.OrderNumber
FROM OrderHeader
GROUP BY OrderHeader.OrderDate
HAVING OrderHeader.OrderDate>#1/1/2015#
WHERE BillTo IN ('PO', 'P.O', 'P.O.')
AND ShipTo NOT IN ('PO', 'P.O', 'P.O.');
```

Can someone please tell us what we're doing wrong here?

> error: Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'OrderHeader.OrderDate>#1/1/2015# WHERE BillTo IN ('PO', 'P.O', 'P.O.') AND ShipTo NOT IN ('PO', 'P.O', 'P.O.')

Comment: wrong how? syntax error? not matching any records? getting wrong records? query jumps up and kicks your dog?

Comment: Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'OrderHeader.OrderDate>#1/1/2015#
WHERE BillTo IN ('PO', 'P.O', 'P.O.')
AND ShipTo NOT IN ('PO', 'P.O', 'P.O.')

Comment: `SELECT
FROM
WHERE
GROUP BY
HAVING`

Comment: Why do you have `#` signs in `#1/1/2015#`?

Comment: you should tag the appropriate database as well. this `#` looks like ms-access

Comment: @RocketHazmat That looks like MS (at least MSAccess) syntax.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT OrderNumber
FROM OrderHeader
WHERE BillTo IN ('PO', 'P.O', 'P.O.')
AND ShipTo NOT IN ('PO', 'P.O', 'P.O.')
AND OrderDate>#1/1/2015#;
```

You don't need a `group by` or `having` clause.

Comment: "Data type mismatch in criteria expression."

This is the new error we get via this code.

Comment: you should then check the datatypes. Unless you specify that in the question, it is difficult to assume.